# Why .NET 4 variance for generic type arguments not also for classes?

Tags: c#-4.0, covariance, contravariance

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Why isn't there generic variance for classes in C# 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2733346/why-isnt-there-generic-variance-for-classes-in-c-4-0)
>   [Why does C# (4.0) not allow co- and contravariance in generic class types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541467/why-does-c-4-0-not-allow-co-and-contravariance-in-generic-class-types)

The new .NET 4.0 co- and contravariance for generic type arguments only works for interfaces and delegates. What is the reason for not supporting it for classes too?

Comment: Not sure what you are talking about here, covariance and contravariance are supported on classes: See this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2009/07/31/c-4-0-co-variance-and-contra-variance.aspx

Comment: That article just shows variance for delegates.

Comment: Who voted to close as "Not a real question" ? This is a perfectly good question...

Comment: Yeah! :) Actually Stackoverflow is full question where people tried to apply the new variance stuff to classes (and naturally failed).

Comment: Related questions: http://goo.gl/4PEW http://goo.gl/R61S http://goo.gl/S7No

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541467/why-does-c-4-0-not-allow-co-and-contravariance-in-generic-class-types that has an answer from Eric Lippert (member of the MS C# team)

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate. We can close this one now.

Comment: It is just an oversight by the Microsoft VM team when they first designed the CLR type system. I guess the would love to support it, but it just wasn't there in the first place and changing the VM so late in the cycle in such an fundamental way might too dangerous. The situation is comparable to Generics in Java. It is just a hack to retrofit some oversights into language. Both the JVM and the CLR have some design flaws: the JVM doesn't know Generics (but supports co-/contravariant classes); the CLR has some basic support for Generics (no higher-kinded types), but lacks support for variance.

Comment: @soc, I doubt this is an oversight, this is a design choice... have you read the answer to this question ?

Comment: @Thomas: Yes I have. Variance is no black magic, the concept is understood well since centuries and is demonstrated to work dozens of times already. In fact with variance and a better compiler it is possible to detect errors at compile time which would have resulted in an undetected error at runtime before. Therefore, support for real variance can make programs more correct. The .NET approach is the same sort of excuse like with Generics in Java; and I'm annoyed that there is no mainstream VM that didn't take the "let's just hack it together" approach to typesystem design.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For type safety, C# 4.0 supports covariance/contravariance ONLY for type parameters marked with **in** or **out**.

If this extended to classes, you'd also have to mark type parameters with in our out and this would end up being very restrictive. This is most likely why the designers of the CLR chose not to allow it. For instance, consider the following class:

```
public class Stack<T>
{
  int position;
  T[] data = new T[100];
  public void Push (T obj)   { data[position++] = obj;  }
  public T Pop()             { return data[--position]; }
}
```

It would be impossible to annotate T as either in our out, because T is used in both input and output positions. Hence this class could never covariant or contravariant - even in C# supported covariance/contravariant type parameters for classes.

Interfaces solve the problem nicely. We can have define two interfaces as follows, and have Stack implement both:

```
public interface IPoppable<out T> { T Pop(); }
public interface IPushable<in T> { void Push (T obj); }
```

Note that T is covariant for IPoppable and contravariant for IPushable. This means T can be either covariant or contravariant - depending on whether you cast to IPoppable or IPushable.

Another reason that covariance/contravariance would be of limited use with classes is it would rule out using type parameters as fields - because fields effectively allow both input and output operations. In fact, it would be hard to write a class that does anything useful at all with a type parameter marked as in or out. Even the simplest case of writing a covariant Enumerable implementation would present a challenge - how would you get source data into the instance to begin with?

Comment: A class type which accepts parameters of type `T` in constructors but no other instance method, and has method which return type `T`, could theoretically be covariant in `T` without any type-safety problems.  The difficulty comes with static variables.  If class `Thing<T>` has a public static field `Foo` of type `int`, `Thing<BaseType>` will have a different `Foo` from `Thing<DerivedType>`.

Answer (score 1):

The .NET team along with the C# and VB.NET team has limited resources, the work they have done on co- and contravariance **solves most of the real world problem**.  Type systems are very complex to get right – a solution that works in 99.9999% of cases is not good enough if it leads to unsafe code in the other cases.

I don’t think the cost/time of supporting  co- and contravariance specs (e.g. “in”/”out”) on class methods is of a great enough value.   I can see very few cases when they would be useable – due to the lack of multiply class inheritance.

**Would you rather had waited for another 6 months for .net so as to get this support?**

---

Another way to think of this is that in .net

- **Interfaces** / delegates – are used to model the **conceptual type system** of an application
- **Class** are used to **implement** the above types
- **Class inheritance** is used to reduce code duplication while doing the above
- **co- and contravariance** is about the **conceptual type system** of an application