# Simple Covariance doesn't seem to work with c# generics

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, covariance

It looks to me like I am having an understanding problem with covariance in c#.
If I have the following classes:

```
class a {
}

class b : a {
}

class A<T> where T: a {
}

class B<T> : A<T> {
}

class C : A<b> {
}
```

And now I do:

```
A<a> t1 = new B<b>();
A<a> t2 = new C();
```

Neither of those work - but why??
Doesn't this article from Microsoft propose, that exactly this should be working?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd799517(v=vs.110).aspx

Why isn't this very simple example not working?

Best regards

Comment: Asked a few times: [why-doesnt-c-sharp-do-simple-type-inference-on-generics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503603/why-doesnt-c-sharp-do-simple-type-inference-on-generics) or [why-generics-of-derived-classes-produces-non-derived-classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431491/why-generics-of-derived-classes-produces-non-derived-classes)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Covariance works like you describe, but there is one important piece:

> A generic class is only covariant if it inherits from an interface
>   marked with the "out" keyword on the covariant generic parameter.

There are a bunch of rules on how you can use this, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) for details.

You aren't inheriting a covariant interface, so your derived assignments will break.

You need something like:

```
IGeneric<out T>
{
}

class a<T> : IGeneric<T>
{
}
```

and so on. Your assignments should work as long as it looks like:

```
IGeneric<Base> = a<Derived>
```

Comment: The assignment should work as long as it looks like: IGeneric<Base> = a<Derived>

Comment: Totally correct, edited to include. Thank you very much!