# Cannot add a subclass of a generic class to a list

Tags: c#, generics

I have an abstract `Content` class and concrete subclasses

```
public abstract class Content

public class ContentA : Content

public class ContentB : Content
```

I also have an abstract generic `ContentSource` class and concrete subclasses

```
public abstract class ContentSource<T> where T : Content

public class SourceX : ContentSource<ContentA>

public class SourceY : ContentSource<ContentB>
```

And I want to have a list of `ContentSource<Content>` objects that are the subclasses of `ContentSource`

```
var ContentSources = new List<ContentSource<Content>>
{
    new SourceX(),
    new SourceY(),
};
```

But this doesn't compile - I get a 'Cannot convert from SourceX to ContentSource' error.

Why does this not work?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be achieved in C# using [covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-generic-modifier), but you'd have to use an interface as the list type:

```
public interface IContentSource<out T> where T : Content {}
public class SourceX : IContentSource<ContentA> {}
public class SourceY : IContentSource<ContentB> {}

var ContentSources = new List<IContentSource<Content>>
{
    new SourceX(),
    new SourceY(),
};
```

[Working example](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAIAYAEqCMBuAWACgNscAWQkgJnWNQGYyA2basgdkwG9jN/sTXK1TlMAWQCGASygAKAJQ8+A1QDdJYTAGEA9lGABTAwGVdEMAGNDAZ0wBeTFEMB3TABlpN4AB4AknoGxsBmFtY+gUYGAHzRxACQ8bxEqonObqFWhgAaijAJ8arpmJnWAJp5BQC+VKqquACccpHBpbYA2ugAugB0AOKGwAAqAJ4ADoaKPQBykgC2hgq1dfyNzfpRIeZZNu04vQPD45MKM/OLy/xVxNdE9EySAEbeYJKWwGw6G8Hct/efLQMAEFMCAvkEDL9iP9UOxAcAAEKg8GbKF3EhMWRGMAAMzehkwAW+pm24XMHyG0UwLgAFoYwAShsj4WiYew2tlkUSIVswoYIsTgEDoqyMZ82mUufC2gKeQiRVUgA)
This is explained nicely here: [`<out T>` vs `<T>` in Generics](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10957035/7586)

You can still use an abstract class, but the list would still have to be a list of the interface:

```
public interface IContentSource<out T> where T : Content {}
public abstract class ContentSource<T> : IContentSource<T> where T : Content {}
public class SourceX : ContentSource<ContentA> {}
public class SourceY : ContentSource<ContentB> {}
```

There is also a great explanation of why it isn't supported for classes: [Why does C# (4.0) not allow co- and contravariance in generic class types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2541467/7586)

Comment: Thank you, that helps a lot! But if I add a method like `string GetLocalPath(T content);` to the IContentSource interface I get a compile error "Invalid variance: The type parameter 'T' must be contravariantly valid"

Comment: @sean2000, The "out" means "T is only used in output positions". You are using it in an input position

Comment: So there's no way of using `T` as a method parameter?

Comment: @sean2000, if you define T as out then you can not use T as an input paramater. It wouldn't make sense anyways. It may be better to explain what you want to do and how you came up with this scheme

Comment: So I have a few different API endpoints where each one is represented by a `ContentSource` class and returns a list of `Content` . The `ContentSource` classes have methods `ContentResultSet<T> Search(Query query)` (to return results of a search)  and `string GetLocalPath(T content)` (to download content and return the path where it is saved)

Answer (score 2):

While [Kobi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7586/kobi) gives a perfect answer how you can get it to work, I will give you a simple answer why it does not work.

In your example, you want to use polymorphism to manage different types that derive from a common base class in a single list of type base class. Something along the lines→

```
public abstract class Base {}
public class DerivedFirst  : Base {}
public class DerivedSecond : Base {}

var first  = new DerivedFirst();
var second = new DerivedSecond(); 
var list   = new List<Base>{first,second}
```

Which is perfectly fine as they derive from the common `Base` class. Now let us take a look at your case. But before that you should understand the difference between an `Open Type` and `Closed Type`. Simply put any generic type without its type parameters are open types and can not be instantiated. `List<>` is an `open type` whereas `List<int>` is a `closed type`. When you create a `closed type` it does not derive from its open definition. It is a completely new type on its own.

```
var i_am_false = typeof(List<int>).IsSubclassOf(typeof(List<>));//this is false
```

Here is your case. You define your classes which will be type arguments.

```
public abstract class Content

public class ContentA : Content

public class ContentB : Content
```

Here you define your sources

```
public abstract class ContentSource<T> where T : Content

public class SourceX : ContentSource<ContentA>   

public class SourceY : ContentSource<ContentB>
```

Putting to words

You have `SourceX` which derives from `ContentSource<ContentA>` which derives from `Object`

You have `SourceY` which derives from `ContentSource<ContentB>` which derives from `Object`

and finally

You have `var ContentSources = new List<ContentSource<Content>>`, which is a list of `ContentSource<Content>` which is in no way connected to `ContentSource<ContentA>` or `ContentSource<ContentB>`. They simply have same implementation with respect to generic parameter.

In the end, let us call

`ContentSource<Content>`  class `M` which derives from `Object`
`ContentSource<ContentA>` class `N` which derives from `Object`
`ContentSource<ContentB>` class `O` which derives from `Object`

and have a look at you are doing→

```
public class SourceX : N{}  

public class SourceY : O{}

var ContentSources = new List<M>{
    new SourceX(),
    new SourceY(),
};
```

Of course it would not work :).
Lastly why it works with covariance please have a look at Kobi's answer.

Comment: This is an excellent and educational answer. It is without doubt correct. However, conceptually, I think the truth of this shows that the language has been incorrectly implemented.