# Class with Iiherited Generic Type convert to class with base Generic Type

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, casting

I have a class with a generic Type:

```
class SomeClass<T>
{

}
```

And two classes -> one inherits fromt the other:

```
class Animal
{

}

class Lion : Animal
{

}
```

Now I want to create a variable of "SomeClass" with the base generic and give it an object witht the inherited type as generic type, like this:

```
    void Test()
    {
        SomeClass<Lion> someLion = new SomeClass<Lion>();

        SomeClass<Animal> someAnimal = someLion;    //Error line

    }
```

The error is:

Cannot implicitly convert type 'VitrasUI.SomeClass' to 'VitrasUI.SomeClass'

From my understanding I should be able to convert it this way, as it works with IEnumerables, too:

```
    void Test1()
    {
        IEnumerable<Lion> listLion = new List<Lion>();

        IEnumerable<Animal> listAnimal = listLion;
    }
```

Comment: Search for covariance and contravariance in C#

Comment: Covariance doesn't work with generic classes, only with interfaces. `IEnumerable` declared as `IEnumerable<out T>`, you can make `SomeClass` interface and make it covariant against `T`

Comment: (and only when declared as `ISomeInterface<out T>`)

Comment: An `IEnumerable<T>` is only for getting _out_ instances of `T`. With a `List<T>` (or `IList<T>`), you promise, that you can also put instances of `T` _in_. Now imagine a `List<Zebra>` being cast as a `List<Animal>` and then putting an instance of `Lion` in there. That would cause some trouble.

Comment: I looked it all up and figured it out. Thanks for your quick responses.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does C# (4.0) not allow co- and contravariance in generic class types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541467/why-does-c-sharp-4-0-not-allow-co-and-contravariance-in-generic-class-types)

Answer (score 1):

With the help of some comments I managed to figure it our quite fast.

What I did:

1) Understand Covariance and Contraviance

(this blog post was pretty easy to understand: http://tomasp.net/blog/variance-explained.aspx/)

2) I added an **interface**, of which the the abstract class (represented by SomeClass) inherits

3) I used the **out** keyword to mark the usage of the generic as covariant in the interface